# Unable to connect to postgres in google cloud sql from localhost node.js project

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I have developed and deployed node.js app on localhost that tries to connect to a database from Google Cloud SQL (postgres).

The database config json is shown below:

```
{
"development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "database": "test",
    "host": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "dialect": "postgres"
}
```

Also, this is the model index.js where I use the connection variables:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/database.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

As for database instance, I have selected Public IP and Authorised my local IP. Also, I can login from PGAdmin and view/edit my database instance from my local machine.

The issue is I can not connect from my app to the database.

Comment: What error do you get? Please add more details to your question

Comment: Hi Cenk, welcome to SO. In order to can help you with the issue, please provide the error message you are getting. You can take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to improve your question.

Comment: What's your issue? Timeout? Error from database?

Comment: While you're answering the above questions, also please try to connect to the database directly using a CLI tool like psql to eliminate any library/js issues.

Comment: Thank you, the weird part is I am not getting an error. I am trying to access an endpoint from Postman. GET https://localhost:8080/test which gets the data from a table from the database. I am not having an error and the request doesn't get to timeout.

Comment: if you go to the Cloud SQL logs, what do you see there?